# NameError: name 'form' is not defined

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to return a custom form from my controller method as given below:

```
searchform=SQLFORM.factory(
    Field('uid', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('uaccount', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))    
if searchform.accepts(request,session):
    response.flash = 'form accepted'
elif searchform.errors:
    response.flash = 'form has errors'       
else:
    response.flash = 'please fill the form'
return dict(form=searchform)
```

In my index.html, I have written following code to render the form:

```
{{=form.custom.begin}}
{{=form.custom.widget.uid}} 
{{=form.custom.widget.uaccount}} 
{{=form.custom.submit}}
{{=form.custom.end}}
```

But I get an error message as : NameError: name 'form' is not defined

I have checked my response using response._vars, it contains form gluon.sqlhtml.SQLFORM object at 0x07D5EFB0

Comment: However if I try to explicitly mention view in controller as 
return response.render('mycontroller/index.html',dict(form=searchform))
it works absolutely fine.

Comment: If I write this line in the view:
    {{form=response._vars['form']}}
Then I can use form as a variable in the rest of the form.

Comment: Something is amiss. I suggest you pack a minimal app that reproduces the problem and attach it to a post on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/web2py).